# Safest practice to execute only part of an app for guest users using the app (that don't sign up)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have an app that populates a map with location markers (incl other details) that are stored in Firebase. Right now users can only view / modify (ie add and/or remove) the locations if they create an account.

But now I want to have a guest option whereby a user who doesn't want to sign up can use the app but only certain functions (such as being able to only view the map and markers). Similar to Youtube, whereby you can use the website/app to watch videos without signing up, but if you do you can use their other functions.

What would be the safest approach to this without compromising the safety of my data?

I did consider hard coding a guest user into the code but that doesn't seem like good practice.

Alternatively, I was thinking maybe I should create a second duplicate Firebase account that only enables users to freely read the data.

What do you think?

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "partially use the app to view the map and markers"? To only give the right to the guests to view but not to create/modify? Or to restrict their access to only the markers and not to the other details? Which database do you use (Firestore, Real Time DB)? What is your database structure?

Comment: Firebase supports guest user logins. You can combine that with database rules to reteive only permissioned data.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes. Like you said, "To only give the right to the guests to view but not to create/modify" and "restrict their access to only the markers and not to the other details"

Comment: @RenaudTarnec to answer you last question. I am using Realtime Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following you responses in the comments, i.e:

1. The requirement are "To only give the right to the guests to view but not to create/modify" and "restrict their access to only the markers and not to the other details"
2. You are using the Real Time database

you could adopt the following approach:

**Firstly**, in your database, separate the content that can be seen by authenticated users (the markers **and the other details**) and the content that can be seen by guests (only the markers). To do so you would duplicate the markers data, as follows (just an example since you didn't share your data structure):

```
-  fullData  <- This node and all children should be only accessible by authenticated users
   - ID1
      - lat: ....
      - long: ....
      - otherDetail1: ...
      - otherDetail2: ...
   - ID2
      - lat: ....
      - long: ....
      - otherDetail1: ...
      - otherDetail2: ...
   ....
-  markersOnly   <- This node and all children can be read by everybody
   - ID1
      - lat: ....
      - long: ....
   - ID2
      - lat: ....
      - long: ....
   ....
```

In order to keep the two nodes in sync, you would use the `update()` method as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), which allows "simultaneous updates to multiple locations in the JSON tree with a **single call**".

**Secondly**, you set-up your security rules in such a way you restrict the right to create/modify/read the data under the `fullData` node  to authenticated users only, but allow everybody to read the data under the `markersOnly` node (and only allow authenticated users to create/modify).

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry you did ask for my data structure. But essentially it looks like what you wrote. Cool. This is closer towards what I am looking for. I'm gonna give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: @Reuben Did you have time to give a go?

Comment: Yup! I did as you said and created another node with different security rules. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
```

With a single line of code, this creates a Firebase Authentication user with a unique UID. While you won't know anything more than the UID (it's anonymous after all), your security rules can likely mostly remain the same. As an added bonus, you can allow those anonymous users to later upgrade their account by signing in, and [linking the two together](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking).

Comment: You're right in the sense that it is the easiest. But I'm looking for more the "functional teaser" approach, whereby the the user can still use the main function (which is to view markers on the map). 

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I've read about Firebase's anonymous authentication, it gives the user a guest pass to use the app in its entirety - just under the anonymity of being a guest user, which is not that approach I'm looking for.

Comment: A perfect example of what I want would be youtube.com, whereby you can still see videos even if you don't sign up. But if you do, you can create playlists, subscribe to channels etc.